# multiple function declarations in different compilation units

Tags: c, linker

zero.c:

```
    int sq();
```

one.c:

```
    int sq(int i) { return i*i; }
```

two.c:

```
    int sq(int i, int j);
```

main.c:

```
    int main() {
        printf("%d\n",sq());
        printf("%d\n",sq(2));
        printf("%d\n",sq(2,3));
    }
```

then I compile each file individually and `gcc zero.o one.o two.o main.o -o main`

`./main` gives

```
1
4
4
```

I'm a little confused as how this would work successfully. what really happens when I call `sq()` or `sq(2)` or `sq(2,3)`

Comment: whats the implementation of two.c?

Comment: I think your linker is getting confused.  I don't think you can actually have 3 methods named the same thing, even if they do have different arguments.  I think your object code is going to be calling one of the functions, not all 3.  I think function 1 is getting called and then the rest are function 2 calls.

Comment: There will be undefined results if you do this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098380/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-function-name-within-c

Comment: Which compiler and version you are using?

Comment: You only have one actual implementation of sq() so that is going to be used every time you call the function. If you call it with the wrong amount of arguments you will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what really happens, have gcc output the assembly for main.o and take a look. I think you will find that when you call sq() the arguments are loaded into the base registers on your machine, and then sq(int i) will do a multiply instruction on the first register. If you pass additional arguments they won't have any affect, and if you don't pass any arguments it will just work on whatever value was previously loaded into that register.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wrote an answer earlier based on what I read in the post. Which was wrong. Here's the correct answer.

zero.c doesn't generate any code. two.c doesn't generate any code.

main.c and one.c are the only files that actually generate code.

Calling a function with one argument, `sq(int i)` in one.c, with no arguments is undefined behaviour (so "anything can happen", including something resembling what you expect in some cases). Calling with two arguments is also undefined behaviour - again, it will not necessarily "go wrong" when you do this, but you it is not guaranteed to work (or do what you expect) - it could for example just as well return 9 because it puts arguments into registers from the last to first.

Comment: Disagree... there is only 1 definition. zero.c & two.c have just prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

zero.c & two.c do not have any function definition. It's only prototype declaration. Thus, it will not create any assembly code having function definition. (hint: compile with `gcc -s` flag to verify.)

Only two.c has function definition. Thus two.s will have a function `sq`, which takes the first argument (generally passed on the stack or the first register of the processor, like eax on intel or r0 in arm) & returns its square.

Since you have not given any  prototype in main.c, the compiler (.c -> .s) will not complain. It may *probably* treat it as `int sq(...)`, but I am not sure about it.

Thus, for 3 different inputs:
`sq()`, `sq(2)`, `sq(2,3)` will all call to the same function, which is declared in two.c.

Now, the outputs for `sq(2)` & `sq(2,3)` are obvious - return square of the first argument passed. The output for `sq()` will depend on what is on the stack/eax/r0 as seen in sq's stack. Seems that it was 1. hint: run under gdb to verify.

Comment: `zero.c` doesn't have any prototype, just a declaration.

Comment: I used to use the terms prototype & delcaration interchangibly... Can you tell me the difference?

Comment: Prototypes are function declaration with a parameter list. `foo()` doesn't mean that `foo` takes no arguments, but that it can take any number of arguments of any type (without using them obviusly, since there are no parameters). A prototype for a function that takes no arguments in C looks like `foo(void)`, you can find some questions about this difference here on SO.

Comment: I see... I am wondering, what can be the use of just declaration? just to tell that there exists some function named foo?

Comment: From C89 I can't see any good reason to not use prototypes, non-prototype function declaration still exist for backward compatibility: before the standardization (*K&R C*) there were no prototypes, they came with C89.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C spec, your code invokes undefined behavior in multiple ways (and possibly more):

- Two declarations of the same function in the same scope use different return or argument types/counts
- For a call to a function without a function prototype in scope, the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters

Since this is undefined behavior, you have no way to predict what will happen.  The result doesn't even necessarily have to be *consistent*.  If you aren't seeing compile-time warnings/errors for this code, then you need to turn up your compiler's warning level.

Adding a prototype in main.c will probably resolve the compiler's warnings with this code.  The linker may still have issues, though, because you have multiple functions with the same name in the same scope and it's not exactly clear which one you want the code to use.