# C linker and duplicate symbols

Tags: c, gcc, llvm

I did an experiment to see what kind of assembly language would be generate if I try to get the same function to compile in there twice. I did the following:

I created two simple test files and their corresponding headers. Let's call them a.c/a.h, and b.c/b.h. Here are the contents of those files:

a.h:

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

int a( void );

#endif
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

int b( void );

#endif
```

a.c:

```
#include "a.h"

int a( void )
{
    return 1;
}
```

b.c:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

int b( void )
{
    return 1 + a();
}
```

I then created a static archive for a:

```
gcc -c a.c -o a.o
ar -rsc a.a a.o
```

and the same for b, including the static archive for a this time:

```
gcc -c b.c -o b.o
ar -rsc b.a a.a b.o
```

At this point, I disassemble the static archive for b to verify that it has assembly code for both functions a() and b(). It does.

Now, I define one last file:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d %d\n", a(), b() );

    return 0;
}
```

and I compile it thusly:

```
gcc main.c a.a b.a -o main
```

This works fine. When I disassemble it, I see the following definitions for a and b in the code:

```
140 0000000000400561 <a>:
141   400561:   55                      push   %rbp
142   400562:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
143   400565:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
144   40056a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
145   40056b:   c3                      retq
146 
147 000000000040056c <b>:
148   40056c:   55                      push   %rbp
149   40056d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
150   400570:   e8 ec ff ff ff          callq  400561 <a>
151   400575:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
152   400578:   5d                      pop    %rbp
153   400579:   c3                      retq
154   40057a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

As you can see, the code has clearly defined b as calling a rather than inlining it, however, there is only one definition of a in the code, no duplicates.

It seems that gcc has either:

1. Detected the duplicate object code and removed the duplicates
   --or--
2. the b archive was used first, and it included the reference to int a(), so the a archive was ignored.

**My question is: is this behavior circumstantial to my test or is it standard, and can I expect the same behavior from other compilers? Obviously duplicate code is one problem, however there could be duplicate global references as well. Is it safe/good practice to build a large application that has multiple dependency paths to the same static archive? Are there less obvious situations than just duplicate symbol names where issues can arise when doing this?**

Asking this because I've been playing with this idea for a project I'm on, and want to make the right choices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with duplicated function name within C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098380/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-function-name-within-c)

Comment: Currently your `b.c` doesn't see the declaration of `a()`. Missing an `#include "a.h"` in `b.c`?

Comment: Suggest dropping the C++ tag

Comment: What happens if you don't include `a.a` in the compilation of main? Does everything link properly? It looks to me like you've got `a.a` and `b.o` inside of archive `b.a`, so will the linker actually find `a.o` inside of `a.a` inside of `b.a`?

Comment: Libraries are only searched if needed. Since `a` has already been imported from `a.a`, the linker doesn't bother searching for `a` in `b.a`.

Comment: C++ tag dropped. Project in question is written entirely in C++, but I agree it doesn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the suggested questions. Functions are defined once, but I'm trying to break the linker with how I include static archives. Linker seems to be robust so it's more of a question of semantics and practices.

Comment: I think that user3386109's answer is the answer that I am looking for; it suggests that dynamic naming has taken care of this. I feel like it would be more likely to have duplicate symbol errors than code included twice in the linking stage.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: is this behavior circumstantial to my test or is it standard, and can I expect the same behavior from other compilers?

As far as the compiler itself is concerned, there is no issue: you have one definition for each function among your sources.

As far as `ar` is concerned, you also have no issue: neither of the archives you built contains any duplicate symbols.

Different linkers may exhibit different behaviors, however.  It is conceivable that some would reject linking archives that contain duplicate external symbols.  Typical UNIX linkers will handle the situation you present, but they may vary in some details, such as whether a duplicate copy of function `a()` is included in the binary.

> Obviously duplicate code is one problem, however there could be duplicate global references as well. Is it safe/good practice to build a large application that has multiple dependency paths to the same static archive?

"Multiple paths to the same static archive" does not seem to be a good characterization of the situation you present.  In neither case do you provide the same archive more than once.  Rather, in the `b` case you provide different archives with duplicate members.  Linkers generally do not have problems with specifying the same archive multiple times in the same link command.  Under some circumstances it may even be necessary to do so; it should not present a problem.

Providing distinct archives with duplicate members *probably* will not present a problem, except possibly for bloating your code with duplicate function implementations.  This is a bit less certain, but I doubt it would present a problem in practice.

Whether that's good practice is a matter of opinion, but I'm inclined to think not.  It's also not clear to me what gain you seen in such an approach.  On the other hand, I won't be sharpening any stakes or preparing any kindling if you decide to go ahead anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your well informed response. I should clarify my 'multiple paths' statement by saying that when I link the binary with a.a and b.a, b.a has functions that are also defined in a.a, but the linker has been smart enough in this case to pick one. I'm concerned with cases where it may not.

Comment: I have a common code archive that is included from multiple binaries, and I also have some of the code from one of those binaries pulled into another one. There are two ways of compiling this project. One is monolithic, one is not. That's the basic idea.