# Why can gcc call undefined functions?

Tags: c

The following code can be compiled and output undefined warnings for functions without including any header files.

```c
// gcc a.c -std=c17
int main(){
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

This makes it impossible for me to define a function with the same name as the library function, as shown in the following code:

```c
int printf(const char* str, ...) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("hello 1\n");
    printf("hello %d\n", 2);
    printf("hello 3\n");
}
```

output：

```c
hello 1
hello 3
```

The first printf and the third call to library functions, but the second call to the function I defined. There are no redefined errors reported here, nor are there always calls to library functions or functions defined by me. Is this a bug in the compiler.

gcc version: gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0

Comment: `printf("hello 1\n");` can be optimized to `puts("hello 1");` I found that gcc can apply this optimization [even with `-O0` option](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TbTTnrsfW).

Comment: GCC silently replaces single-argument `printf` calls with `puts`. And the two snippets are unrelated, `int main() {printf("hello %d\n", 2);}` by itself does work too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c)

Comment: You have to differ between *un**declared***, and *un**defined*** symbols. A declaration is telling the compiler that a symbol exists, somewhere. A definition is the actual implementation of that symbol. A definition can also be a declaration, if the symbol haven't been declared before. What the `<stdio.h>` header does is to *declare* the function `printf`, but it doesn't define it. The definition is in a library that is automatically linked.

Comment: The output is the same whether or not you `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3098380/1025391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it should be noted that defining a function with the same name as a library function is considered [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by the C standard.  That being said, implementations like gcc allow this by defining such library functions as *weak symbols*, meaning that implementations may define their own version of such functions to override the library versions.

The `printf` function is *defined* as part of the standard C library that is linked in by default.  It is *declared* in the stdio.h file.

When you compile the first piece of code you may get a warning that either `printf` is undeclared or that a default declaration is being used.  The default implicit declaration for a function `f` is `int f()`, i.e. a function that takes an unspecified number of arguments and returns an `int`.  This is (almost) compatible with the actual declaration, so in practice it ends up working as expected.

The problem with the second piece of code has nothing to do with the missing header.  In fact, since your definition is compatible with the declaration in the header, there would be no error if you did so and the behavior would be the same.

The difference in behavior is due to optimizations being done by gcc.  When it sees a call to `printf` with only a format string ending in a newline, it optimizes this to a call to `puts` as the observable behavior would be the same.  If you compile with `-S` and look at the generated assembly, you'll see that's exactly what happens:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts                      // printf call optimized away
        mov     esi, 2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf                    // printf call not optimized
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        call    puts                      // printf call optimized away
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Of course, this optimization arguably shouldn't apply if a user-defined implementation of `printf` is given.  If you compile with the flag `-fno-builtin-printf`, the standard `printf` function won't be linked in and this optimization will not happen.